# Как убрать анимацию при переключении табов в Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

При переключении табов их содержимое анимируется, подобно слайдам в слайдере. Как отключить эту анимацию?

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Answer (score 0):

Обычным CSS

```
md-tab-content {
  transition: none;
}
```